# Highlight entire rows when values in a single column are unique (conditional formatting)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, cell-format

I have a spreadsheet with several columns of data and a couple thousand rows. Each row contains a product and each column contains details about that product.

Example:

| Row # | Category ID | Item | Item revision | Item sku |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 1 | baseball | 1 | 00012 |
| 2. | 1 | baseball | 2 | 00013 |
| 3. | 1 | baseball | 3 | 00014 |
| 4. | 10 | bat. | 1 | 00025 |
| 5. | 10. | bat | 2 | 00026 |
| 6. | 20 | glove. | 1. | 00032 |
| 7. | 20 | glove. | 2. | 00033 |

I need to highlight (I'm hoping through Conditional formatting) the entire row of each first unique category ID (In this instance, rows 1,4,6). 
I can successfully highlight unique cells in a single column using conditional highlighting, and I am pretty sure I can highlight a cell based on a unique value in another column. However, I am having difficulty getting a unique cell value in the category ID column to trigger highlighting for the whole row containing that unique value.

In my specific case, I am using this conditional rule to highlight the first of each unique value in my category ID column:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1)=1
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just take whatever you’re doing and apply it to the whole row.  P.S. You might get more help if you say / show exactly what you’re doing now; i.e., what formula you’re using for the conditional formatting that highlights unique cells.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my original post to include what I am currently doing to highlight the first column elements.

Comment: Try `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,$A1)=1`. See [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9) if you want more details on relative vs absolute cell addresses

Comment: Man that did it... that stinkin' missing $. :).

Thanks CN.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unless I’m misunderstanding
(do you want to highlight your header row?),
you need to start your range from row 2:

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2)=1
```

Then refer to Column A absolutely by using `$A`. 
Select all the data you want to format, create new rule,
Use a formula to determine which cells to format, and use

```
=COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A2)=1
```

So this:

[image: "new rule" dialog (with instructions/formula as described above)]

gives you this:

[image: resulting formatting (first row of each unique value is highlighted)]

Comment: Thanks Scott. This is a better, more full answer. You are correct in that I do not want headers selected so going to row two is what I should have done. Thanks for the pointer there. I was manually deselecting the header at the formatting creation. That's far less efficient. 

If I hadn't missed the leading $ at A$1 all would have been right with the world... or at least my sheet. :)

Thanks for your time. I appreciate the detailed answer.